# Conditional Probability Question, Simple but answer not coming to mind...

Tags: probability

So I have this problem:

"40% of our students taking Calc I are freshman while the remainder are sophomores. 70% of sophomores pass Calc I, whereas only 60% of freshmen pass Calc I. If a student passes Calc I, what is the probability that he was a freshman?"

Using conditional probability rules, actually i used a tree diagram, I found the porbability of a student passing the exam to be 66% or .66

However, I'm not sure how to calculate the probability that he was a freshman. I feel like it's simple, I know it's simple, I'm just not thinking of it...

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

Imagine that the total number of students is $100$. If $70$% of $60$ sophomores pass the course, that’s $42$ students, leaving $18$ sophomores who failed. Similarly, $60$% of $40$, or $24$, freshmen passed, and $16$ failed. At this point you can complete the following table, as shown:

$$\begin{array}{r|cc|c}
&\text{Fr.}&\text{So.}&\text{Total}\\ \hline
\text{Pass}:&24&42&66\\
\text{Fail}:&16&18&34\\ \hline
\text{Total}:&40&60&100
\end{array}$$

Now look at the $66$ who passed: $24$ of them were freshmen, so the probability that one of them chosen at random is a freshman must be

$$\frac{24}{66}=\frac4{11}\;.$$

Does it matter that I assumed $100$ students altogether? No: if there are $n$ students, the table becomes

$$\begin{array}{r|cc|c}
&\text{Fr.}&\text{So.}&\text{Total}\\ \hline
\text{Pass}:&0.24n&0.42n&0.66n\\
\text{Fail}:&0.16n&0.18n&0.34n\\ \hline
\text{Total}:&0.40n&0.60n&n
\end{array}$$

and the probability calculation becomes

$$\frac{0.24n}{0.66n}=\frac4{11}\;,$$

just as before.

Answer (score 1):

$$P(\text{ freshman}|\text{ pass})=\frac{P(\text{ freshman}\text{ and pass})}{P(\text{pass})}=\frac{0.6\cdot0.4}{0.6\cdot0.4+0.7\cdot0.6}=\frac{0.24}{0.66}=\frac{4}{11}$$ So, the 0.66 you had, was correct, but it was only the denominator of the required probability.

Comment: Numerator in your fraction is incorrect, it should be $0.6 * 0.4$.

Comment: Thank you! I had the equation written out already and was confused about what numbers to plug in. Makes sense now.

Comment: @AndreiRykhalski Thank you, I corrected it.

Comment: @AlecLeonK There was a mistake in the numerator, see the correction!

Answer (score 0):

Let assume that total number of students is 100. Then 40 of them are freshmen, 60 are sophomores. 24 freshmen passed Calc I, 42 sophomores passed Calc I, so the chosen student is among these 24+42 = 66 students. Hope you can continue by yourself from here.

Answer (score 0):

The probability you are looking for is $P(freshman|passed)$.  Using bayes theorem, we have $$P(freshman|passed) = \frac{P(passed|freshman)P(freshman)}{P(passed)} = \frac{(.6)(.4)} {(.4)(.6)+(.6)(.7)} = \frac{.24}{.66} = \frac{6}{11}$$